# How to increase label's size

Tags: python, matplotlib, label, size

Is there any way to increase the size of labels by adding a command close to labels. Something like labelsize?

```
    plt.plot(K,L,label='1')
    plt.plot(K,M,label='2')
    plt.plot(K,P,label='3')
    plt.plot(K,V,label='4')
    plt.plot(K,Z,label='5')
    plt.show()
```

So my aim is to increase labels size. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the legend size, There are many ways to do this more efficiently.

Let's say you can pass `fontsize` inside `legend` function and it will change all the `fontsize` of the `labels` automatically. Refer below example.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as mpla
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
S = np.sin(T)
S1 = np.sin(T+(np.pi+10))
line, = plt.plot(T, S,'b', lw=3, label="sine wave")
line1, = plt.plot(T, S1,'r', lw=3, label="cosine wave")
plt.grid()
plt.legend(title="legend title", fontsize=18, title_fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or you can also Globally use the setting font sizes via `rcParams` should be done with

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 16

# or

params = {'axes.labelsize': 16,
          'axes.titlesize': 16}
plt.rcParams.update(params)

# or

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rc('axes', labelsize=16, titlesize=16)

# or 

axes = {'labelsize': 16,
        'titlesize': 16}
mpl.rc('axes', **axes)
```